# Como converter variável do tipo number para string no typescript?

Tags: typescript

Tenho este código:

```
jogar(escolha) {
    var jogadorEscolha = 0;
    var jogadorPontuacao = 0;
    var computadorEscolha = 0;
    var computadorPontuacao = 0;
    var ganhador = -1;

    jogadorEscolha = escolha;
    computadorEscolha = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

    //1 - Fogo
    //2 - Água
    //3 - Planta

    if ((jogadorEscolha == 1) && (computadorEscolha == 1)) {
        ganhador = 0;
    } else if ((jogadorEscolha == 1) && (computadorEscolha == 2)) {
        ganhador = 2;
    } else if ((jogadorEscolha == 1) && (computadorEscolha == 3)) {
        ganhador = 1;
    } else if ((jogadorEscolha == 2) && (computadorEscolha == 1)) {
        ganhador = 1;
    } else if ((jogadorEscolha == 2) && (computadorEscolha == 2)) {
        ganhador = 0;
    } else if ((jogadorEscolha == 2) && (computadorEscolha == 3)) {
        ganhador = 2;
    } else if ((jogadorEscolha == 3) && (computadorEscolha == 1)) {
        ganhador = 2;
    } else if ((jogadorEscolha == 3) && (computadorEscolha == 2)) {
        ganhador = 1;
    } else if ((jogadorEscolha == 3) && (computadorEscolha == 3)) {
        ganhador = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById("jogadorEscolha1").classList.remove('selecionado');
    document.getElementById("jogadorEscolha2").classList.remove('selecionado');
    document.getElementById("jogadorEscolha3").classList.remove('selecionado');
    document.getElementById("computadorEscolha1").classList.remove('selecionado');
    document.getElementById("computadorEscolha2").classList.remove('selecionado');
    document.getElementById("computadorEscolha3").classList.remove('selecionado');

    document.getElementById("jogadorEscolha" + jogadorEscolha).classList
        .add('selecionado');
    document.getElementById("computadorEscolha" + computadorEscolha).classList
        .add('selecionado');

    if (ganhador == 0) {
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = 'Empate';
    } else if (ganhador == 1) {
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = 'Jogador ganhou!';
        jogadorPontuacao++;
    } else if (ganhador == 2) {
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = 'Jogador perdeu!';
        computadorPontuacao++;
    }

    document.getElementById('jogadorPontos').innerHTML = jogadorPontuacao;
    document.getElementById('computadorPontos').innerHTML = computadorPontuacao;
    //essas últimas duas linhas que estão dando erro

}
```

Estou tentando pegar os valores da variaveis jogadorPontuacao
e computadorPontuacao, para retorná-las à um espaço de id jogadoPontos 
e computadorPontos, porém o typescript diz que a variavel é do type number 
e não é assimilável ao type string, por conta do innerHTML, como faço pra converter as variáveis para string depois de pegar seu valor para que o
typescript aceite o código, ou existe alguma outra maneira de retornar o valor
pelo document.getElementById para o HTML sendo do tipo inteiro?

Comment: Descreva mais detalhes sobre o seu problema, assim podemos ajudar de forma mais efetiva

Comment: E onde está o código TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se percebi bem a sua questão contudo deixo aqui a dica.

Método [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

```js
var jogadorPontuacao = 1;
var computacaoPontuacao = 2;

console.log( `${ jogadorPontuacao.toString() } - ${ computacaoPontuacao.toString() }` );
```